# Escape + Quotation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

What I am trying to do is put escape charater in the python string. Let me explain.

I got string

```
str = 'station and the "Tren Bach"'
```

This `str` is then formatted into the big 'SQL' query, making `malformed exception` due to double quotation mark in the middle of "Tren Bach".

So I tried to pre-process before formatting as below.

```
str = str.replace ('"', '\"')
sql.format(str)
```

But in the sql string, escape was not there.

Secondly I tried,

```
str = str.replace ('"', '\\"')
sql.format (str)
```

But at this moment, double escape was shown in the sql.

What I am expected is as follows.

```
str = 'station and the \"Tren Bach\"'
```

So that the `str` does not make trouble in the sql statement.

Would you recommend other way?

Comment: Try using `str.replace('"', r'\"')` and use it in your SQL. See if that works.

Comment: Sidenote: you are overwriting the str built-in type in your example.

Comment: Oh, nope. I use other variable name. I just made a pseudo code for the explanation. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should use the parameterizing offered by the `execute()` method of the cursor instead of constructing the query on your own. Everything else will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @zedfoxus your recommendation doesn't work. It makes \\ double escape for me.

Comment: \\ is what python shows you. Try `print('{}'.format( str.replace('"', r'\"') ))` and you will see that a single \ is seen. While we are consistently talking about slashes and such, what exactly are you trying to doing? If you can show the end-game, we might be able to propose multiple options to get there.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery uses [slightly different escaping](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical) then standard SQL. You need quotes around the value with quotes in the query, similar to Python. E.g.:

```
s = '''SELECT ... WHERE my_field='station and the "Tren Bach"' '''
#               note quotes here ^                  and here ^
```